# Concatenation of iterators

Tags: algorithm, scala, binary-tree

I saw this example in "Programming in Scala" chapter 24 "Collections in depth". This example shows two alternative ways to implement a tree:

1. by extending `Traversable[Int]` - here the complexity of `def foreach[U](f: Int => U): Unit` would be `O(N)`.
2. by extending `Iterable[Int]` - here the complexity of `def iterator: Iterator[Int]` would be `O(N log(N))`.

This is to demonstrate why it would be helpful to have two separate traits, `Traversable` and `Iterable`.

```
  sealed abstract class Tree
  case class Branch(left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
  case class Node(elem: Int) extends Tree

  sealed abstract class Tree extends Traversable[Int] {
    def foreach[U](f: Int => U) = this match {
     case Node(elem) => f(elem)
     case Branch(l, r) => l foreach f; r foreach f
    }
  }

  sealed abstract class Tree extends Iterable[Int] {
    def iterator: Iterator[Int] = this match {
      case Node(elem) => Iterator.single(elem)
      case Branch(l, r) => l.iterator ++ r.iterator
    }
  }
```

Regarding the implementation of `foreach` they say:

> traversing a balanced tree takes time proportional to the number of
>   elements in the tree. To see this, consider that for a balanced tree
>   with `N` leaves you will have `N - 1` interior nodes of class Branch. So
>   the total number of steps to traverse the tree is `N + N - 1`.

That makes sense. :)

However, they mention that the concatenation of the two iterators in the `iterator` method has time complexity of `log(N)`, so the total complexity of the method would be `N log(N)`:

> Every time an element is produced by a concatenated iterator such as
>   `l.iterator ++ r.iterator`, the computation needs to follow one
>   indirection to get at the right iterator (either `l.iterator`, or
>   `r.iterator`). Overall, that makes `log(N)` indirections to get at a leaf
>   of a balanced tree with N leaves. So the cost of visiting all elements of a tree went up from about `2N` for the `foreach` traversal method to `N log(N)` for the traversal with `iterator`.

????

Why does the computation of the concatenated iterator need to get at a leaf of the left or right iterator?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  The concatenated iterator needs to "get at" **every** element (leaf) below it. Any particular leaf will be supplied by either the `l.iterator` or the `r.iterator`.  The number of indirections traversed to get to a leaf is exactly the depth of the tree, if the tree is balanced.  Thus for N leaves, log(N) traversals to get to any particular leaf.

Comment: @jwvh updated my question. As you can see, the `foreach` method also visits every leaf. But the total complexity is only O(N). While the complexity of `iterator` is `O(N log(N))`. Apparently, applying `++` on `iterator`s adds to the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The pun on "collections *in depth*" is apt. The depth of the data structure matters.

When you invoke `top.iterator.next()`, each interior `Branch` delegates to the iterator of the `Branch` or `Node` below it, a call chain which is `log(N)`.

You incur that call chain on every `next()`.

Using `foreach`, you visit each `Branch` or `Node` just once.

Edit: Not sure if this helps, but here is an example of eagerly locating the leaves but lazily producing the values. It would stackoverflow or be slower in older versions of Scala, but the implementation of chained `++` was improved. Now it's a flat chain that gets shorter as it's consumed.

```
sealed abstract class Tree extends Iterable[Int] {
  def iterator: Iterator[Int] = {
    def leafIterator(t: Tree): List[Iterator[Int]] = t match {
      case Node(_) => t.iterator :: Nil
      case Branch(left, right) => leafIterator(left) ::: leafIterator(right)
    }
    this match {
      case n @ Node(_) => Iterator.fill(1)(n.value)
      case Branch(left @ Node(_), right @ Node(_)) => left.iterator ++ right.iterator
      case b @ Branch(_, _) =>
        leafIterator(b).foldLeft(Iterator[Int]())((all, it) => all ++ it)
    }
  }
}

case class Branch(left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree {
  override def toString = s"Branch($left, $right)"
}
case class Node(elem: Int) extends Tree {
  def value = {
    Console println "An expensive leaf calculation"
    elem
  }
  override def toString = s"Node($elem)"
}

object Test extends App {
  // many leaves
  val n = 1024 * 1024
  val ns: List[Tree] = (1 to n).map(Node(_)).toList
  var b = ns
  while (b.size > 1) {
    b = b.grouped(2).map { case left :: right :: Nil => Branch(left, right) }.toList
  }
  Console println s"Head: ${b.head.iterator.take(3).toList}"
}
```

Comment: In the code I quoted, where do you see a call to `iterator.next()`?

Comment: "Every time an element is produced by a concatenated iterator" is another way of saying "next".  Perhaps your phrase "the computation of the concatenated iterator" means you're thinking only of constructing the iterator (which only walks left edges eagerly, since `++` takes a by-name parameter. I think "visiting all elements" also means "producing all the values", by iterating over them.

Comment: Are you saying that Iterator.next() is called when the Iterator for the tree is created (i.e. when Iterator.++(...) is called)? It does not look like that from the code (sebszyller's answer). It looks like Tree.foreach(...) and Tree.iterator() have the same complexity, O(2N) = O(N), do you agree with that?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. Yes, I agree with that. I'm saying the text is talking about the cost of iterating, not the cost of composing the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In this implementation, the topmost branch does NOT know how many elements there are in its `left` and `right` sub-branches.

Therefore, the iterator is built recursively with the *divide and conquer* approach which is clearly represented in the `iterator` method - you get to each node (`case Branch`), you produce the iterator of the single node `case Node => ...` and then you join them.

Without getting into each and every node, it would not know what elements there are and how the tree is structured (odd branches allowed vs not allowed etc.).

EDIT:
Let's have a look inside the `++` method on `Iterator`.

```
def ++[B >: A](that: => GenTraversableOnce[B]): Iterator[B] = new Iterator.JoinIterator(self, that)
```

and then at `Iterator.JoinIterator`

```
  private[scala] final class JoinIterator[+A](lhs: Iterator[A], that: => GenTraversableOnce[A]) extends Iterator[A] {
    private[this] var state = 0 // 0: lhs not checked, 1: lhs has next, 2: switched to rhs
    private[this] lazy val rhs: Iterator[A] = that.toIterator
    def hasNext = state match {
      case 0 =>
        if (lhs.hasNext) {
          state = 1
          true
        } else {
          state = 2
          rhs.hasNext
        }
      case 1 => true
      case _ => rhs.hasNext
    }
    def next() = state match {
      case 0 =>
        if (lhs.hasNext) lhs.next()
        else {
          state = 2
          rhs.next()
        }
      case 1 =>
        state = 0
        lhs.next()
      case _ =>
        rhs.next()
    }

    override def ++[B >: A](that: => GenTraversableOnce[B]) =
      new ConcatIterator(this, Vector(() => that.toIterator))
  }
```

From that we can see that joining iterators just creates a recursive structure in the `rhs` field. Furthermore, let's focus on it a bit more.
Consider an even tree with structure `level1 [A]; level2 [B][C]; level 3[D][E][F][F]`

When you call `JoinIterator` on the iterator you preserve the existing `lhs` iterator. However, you always `.toIterator` on `rhs`. Which means that for each subsequent level, the `rhs` part will be reconstructed. So for `B ++ C` you get that looks like `A.lhs (stands for B)` and `A.rhs (stands for C.toIterator)` where `C.toIterator` stands for `C.lhs and C.rhs` etc. Thus, the added complexity.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - of course every node should be reached at least once - but  that would give time complexity of O(N), as they explained in the alternative `Traversable[Int]` implementation. However once the two sub-branches are calculated, they say that applying `++` on them would require `log(N)` operations (and I don't understand why they say so). So the total complexity of the `iterator` method would be N log(N). Here N is the number of leaves (Nodes), hence the total elements in the tree is ≈ 2N.

Comment: Therefore the question is not structured properly since you do know why you have to access each element. You are asking about time complexity instead. You should update the original question so that it does not confuse people anymore.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. I believe I asked why concatenating two iterators would cost O(log(N)), not why producing them. Anyway, I have updated my question.

Comment: Both recurse through the tree and neither knows the depth. You do have to know that `++` produces a lazy iterator, and that it doesn't eagerly buffer the elements, for instance. By coincidence, I tried to add similar doc, but perhaps more words are necessary: https://github.com/scala/scala.github.com/pull/551/files

Comment: True, iterator is indeed lazy. I will investigate more and update the answer once I find something. That link is on point when it comes to double iteration @som-snytt

Comment: You can consider my answer, and keep in mind `iterator.toIterator` is just itself, nothing is constructed. But what happens when you call `next`?

Comment: I think the problem here is that we start to discuss the Scala's implementation of `Iterator` that uses by `by-name` and `lazy` parameters to optimize the right-hand side of the iterator. Whereas if we looked at it as if it was eagerly evaluated code (that is logical concept of the code / pseudocode / whatever) then the answer would be indeed true. Put me right if I am wrong, though @som-snytt

Comment: I'm not sure what the words mean at the bottom of your answer. But I'll add that they improved `++` in 2.12; the new code is educational.